# Rename files with multiple periods with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have files in a folder that I would like to remove the periods and replace with another symbol.

My files are named like this:

```
filename 12.31.15.pdf
filename 03.18.14.pdf
filename 02.17.15.pdf
```

I have to run two PowerShell scripts, one for changing the symbols and the other one for renaming files with back to the .pdf extenstion.

Is there a way to use one command for this?

I'm using the commands below:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.pdf" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace(".", "-")}
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*-pdf" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("-pdf", ".pdf")}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the replacement on the basename and append the extension:

```
... | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Basename.Replace('.', '-') + $_.Extension }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansgar's reply works perfectly and i'll probably be replacing the below with it in my scripts now, if you want something significantly less readable you can try this though, it will match all but the last `.`

```
'a.word.thing.txt' -replace '\.(?=[^.]*\.)','-'
a-word-thing.txt
```